# Wagtail filtering on fields in subclasses of Page

Tags: wagtail

I've been searching the documentation trying to understand if I can filter on page subclass fields the same way I can search on them.

From my experiments search filters must contain only the fields that are defined on the filtered type.

Is this the case? If so, is there any plans on implementing such a thing?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: I would like to filter using elasticsearch on a subpage field using the Page model(Page.objects.filter(new_field='xxx').search()), thus the response will be all pages that have that field with that value.

Comment: I don't know about using elastic search for the filter, but you should be able to use the Django ORM and your database to `.filter()` just like you would with any Django model.

Comment: You can't filter on the database from Page class using child fields.